# How to do a .io tld registry domain transfer to a friend

Tags: domain-transfer

I've a domain with nic.io registry. The domain is directly under registry control and not with any registrar. I need to transfer the domain to one of my friends, I've looked everywhere but could not find an option to transfer domain from user to user. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your friend register an account at NIC.IO and then follow the instructions below, or alternatively change whois information to that of your friends including email changes. With any service provider always check their [**faq**](http://www.nic.io/faq.xzx) page, or alternatively better yet! [**contact**](https://www.nic.io/contact.xzx) them!

> [SOURCE](http://www.nic.io/faq.xzx#transfer_inner)
>
> How do I transfer my domain between two accounts at NIC.IO?
>
> ```
> Login to the account A
> Set an AuthCode on the domain.
> Log-out (from account A)
> Login to account B
> Go to More Options > Transfer control of my Domain from a Reseller to me.
> Enter the domain name and AuthCode
> ```
>
> If the AuthCode matches, the domain name will be transferred
>   immediately.